# QGIS compiles with Qt Creator error

Tags: qgis, compilation

I followed the steps in this article http://linfiniti.com/2011/06/using-qtcreator-with-qgis/ to compile QGIS on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with Qt Creator.

I got the latest source for master with git.

I get the following error:

```
make[2]: No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libQtXml.so', needed by 'output/lib/libqgis_core.so.1.9.90'.  Stop. <br>
make[1]:  [src/core/CMakeFiles/qgis_core.dir/all] Error 2
make:  [all] Error 2 <br>
11:30:10: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project qgis1.9.90 (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Looks like it can't find the `libQtXml.so` file. On my machine it's residing under:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4.8.1 and
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4.8
```

How do I tell `cmake` where to look in one of these directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the CMakeCache.txt file solved the problem.